# How can I use regex in Python to extract the string?

Tags: python, regex

I have to extract a string from a network response which looks like shown below:

```
Hello, did you get this message?
I want to check it,
let me know!

Here is your encrypted text:
96a1e3424f4cfa23db131173d7f8c93396a1e3424f4cfa23db131173d7f8c933182bc4e99a47abb5deaa51741527dd2b478746563aecc40d5d6f6597370338a7

Some more text:
```

The response contains "\r\n" or if checked on Linux, then "\n"

How can I extract the hash from above message?

I wrote something like below but it did not extract the hash:

```
import re

# data corresponds to network response which contains the \r\n characters

matchObj = re.match( r'(.*?)your encrypted text:\r\n(.*)\r\n.*', data)

if matchObj:
    print matchObj.group(2)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your regex does not fit your text at all.

Comment: Where is `your encrypted text:` in your input?

Comment: I updated it now. That string is in the input itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the input one line at a time (using `readlines()` or `split('\n')`) and do this:

```
for line in lines:
    match = re.match('^([0-9a-f]+)$', line)
    if match:
        print(match.groups(1)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's okay that you don't use regex, try it:

```
lines = open(file_name, 'r').read().splitlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.strip() == "your encrypted text:":
        my_text = lines[i + 1]
        break
```